# Does transforming postGIS geographic data to EPSG:4326 , makes them geographic?

Tags: postgis, epsg, geography-data-type, geometry-data-type

I am reading [this](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/clusterindex.html) about "Clustering on Indices" and in 25.2 says that

> The geohash algorithm only works on data in geographic
> (longitude/latitude) coordinates, so we need to transform the
> geometries (to EPSG:4326, which is longitude/latitude) at the same
> time as we hash them.
> `CREATE INDEX nyc_census_blocks_geohash ON nyc_census_blocks (ST_GeoHash(ST_Transform(geom,4326)));`

I was under the impression that `EPSG:4326` is available to both geometry and geography data. Also I thought that you can have geographic data by setting the column type as "geography" when creating a table or by geometry casting using the `::geography`

Does the transformation to EPSG:4326 automatically turns the geometry to geography data?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing coordinate systems and data types. Geometry and geography are data types in PostGIS, which can have one of a number of coordinate systems, of which EPSG:4326 is one. EPSG:4326 is a coordinate system classified as a geographic coordinate system.

Comment: Ok. So, please help me understand the example. 4326 is a geographic coordinate system, but is used on a geometric data type and that is fine and normal?

Comment: Not quite. It's not a 'geometric data type', it's a geometry because that's what that data type is called in PostGIS. But otherwise correct.

Comment: Ah, yes, so "4326 is a geographic coordinate system, but is used on a geometry data type". So the example has "geometries", so geometry data type and uses EPSG4326 to convert them to another coordinate system, a geographic coordinate system. The coordinate system changes, the data type remains geometry. Yes, I see it. Now I have to revisit the chapter about projections and coordinates system, which I hate. Anyway, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

No, transforming to `EPSG:4326` does not make the data a geography type. According to [this link](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geography.html), other systems (e.g. Oracle) may treat `EPSG:4326` as geography automatically (but not PostGIS):

> Different spatial databases have different approaches for “handling
>   geographics”
>
> Oracle attempts to paper over the differences by transparently doing 
>   geographic calculations when the SRID is geographic.
>
> SQL Server uses two spatial types, “STGeometry” for Cartesian data and
>   “STGeography” for geographics.
>
> Informix Spatial is a pure Cartesian extension to Informix, while
>   Informix  Geodetic is a pure geographic extension.
>
> *Similar to SQL Server, PostGIS uses two types, “geometry” and “geography”.*

Note also that the word "geographic" here can be ambiguous. For CRS, a geographic CRS simply means one that uses lat, long (and often the associated spheric/spheroid geometry instead of planar geometry). For data types, as pointed out in @notkilroy's answer and the link above, `geography` is a different data type from the `geometry` type.

Technically, nothing prevents one to use lat, long in geometry types. It's just an unprojected CRS.

You can use `SELECT * FROM geography_columns;` to verify if a transformed column becomes a geography type.